# c++11: how to produce "spurious failures" upon compare_exchange_weak?

Tags: c++, cpu-architecture, stdatomic

Is there a way that we can write some code to produce a "spurious failures" for the "weak" version of compare_exchange? While the same code should work well for compare_exchange_strong?

I wish to see the real difference between the "weak" and "strong" version of 2 apis, any sample for it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For purposes of testing, it might be simplest to wrap it with a function that deliberately returns `false` once out of every 1000 calls, or something like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need a non-x86 CPU, typically one that uses [load-linked / store-conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional) like ARM or AArch64 (before ARMv8.1).  x86 `lock cmpxchg` implements CAS_strong, and there's nothing you can do to weaken it and make it possibly fail when the value in memory does match.

CAS_weak can compile to a single LL/SC attempt; CAS_strong has to compile to an LL/SC retry loop to only fail if the compare was false, not merely from competition for the cache line from other threads. ([As on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMwA7KSuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEEhqkAA6oCoRODB7evgHBaRmOAuGRMSzxiVzJdpgOWUIETMQEOT5%2BQbaY9sUMjc0EpdFxCUm2TS1teZ0KE4MRwxWj1QCUtqhexMjsHOb%2BEcjeWCb%2BbkxELHim/tgmGgCCd/cRBADUB8SYbIIA%2Bm73Qh%2BAHdMEwANYQWboEAgc6oS7XNwvE7YV7mABsTBWJkCVgerwJ70Er086DR/gAIq8mAA6WioJjoSEEaEgNgsEgATx%2BJCwxB%2BnwMqkw6Gx/jx90Jr0%2BBE2DGpNLQLBSzUwP0wqmQCEMwDVIPBEFJpBJtHQ1i4xqhMPZXJ5xD5Au6TGFopOEpxFKeTxeROQn2%2BBD%2BAJ%2Bs2IAmAzNZcIRJyRghRaLMmOxuKeUp9pPJVNp9MZketX1tvISjqFIrFEqlMrlCqVKs%2B6s12qMatD4cNpuNpPNlpZBY5xG5xf5gud5bdXsCnoeHDWtE4AFZeH4OFpSKhOG5rNZXgoNltMIn/DxSARNLO1ghQXzKGswfkaRoAJzosxcJ9P49mQJSAAc%2Bk4SRl3PddOF4BQQGSM9V1nUg4FgJA6zoBJyEoJD6ESYAuDfPg6AIBIIIgWIQNiCJmk5TgTyVAMAHkGFoCiYNILAWB1cQmPwT56gAN0wCCmI1OovHwyjeBeboQNoPBYmIciPCwECCGIPAWFEtYqAMYAFAANTwTAgRolJGFEmRBBEMR2CkUz5CUNQQN0C0DCMFBt0sfRpIgyA1lQFJen4gBaGj/HA7o6l6FwGHcTx2j0MIFnKSo9EKTIBCmPwLWS3ohgS5Yuh6Bo5jSvRanqAR%2BhabKRiqcYBiKi1ZgGSqliqNY902bY9CUzAdh4OdF2ApiNw4VRf3Rfz0UkV5gGQZBXmwmkuFeCAt0saxjVwQgSCPC1Xg8ZVkOIbaVl4aCtBWS9r1GCA7xAMwnxpBdAg0SRJHRQJ/AXfwnwXd9pHnDggNIFc1yG8DINPc81ngqAYEQFB4RSA7UIgdDRmaFgJuAT9khoWh8OIQjiKY0jmEHEzqMYAg6IYkCWLYnY104sK8F4/i10E5BhJ6sTBAkpipJkuSMAZk7lNU7hYI0pgtN0/TDOMiXrPM8QrP4QRFBUdQmN0Mx9B1FzVrcgXPOu9dfKyAKgtefyWGQFIvBOCk0BaDV/KYT6Qvy5wIFcOqQkiprEoy9IUuyaK8mDooskD3KSt6crWnD9K8uZsq5hj6qGsmJPivT%2BKqokVr9w6i0uu5vqOCXIGQKG%2B4ACUAFkJqmmbXnu/wlpWqw3NeDaiEOvYdr2xGMKPMxjohmDztIe9/H8Gk58Xpfl4AgHeFUhcNBpb9Pzu9ENF/T9fwXBdq8GsDbHB07YOhiBEIRpGKBRh%2BMNhYgMckLH/BxvCCMoIm1wk3IuTeEtF6KMUZl8emtM8BcUcKzECHMuYmXEv9NcAtZKDnkiLU8Ys1J8E0jpPSBkjIrhPGrYQogVbSAoRrOy2sAh62cqYQ2NhjbwG8ubAQlsO422aFqR26NuK/gWm7T2qc/A%2B0in7OKZQC6R1Dn7TK0d87NWKqFUqfRCo53qho%2BOec5FqPqto3Iycs7zEMUHIu7VLK4O6vg/6Vdga8Fro3Zu01Zrt07q5Gwvd8D922saYeB0jz%2BAntfaeV5GRXQroDVSkh7qBDMBoN6GgvrVHRFIU%2BzjQIcDBlBSGN054L2XqUueq9gpnxBhfCJFczADWqXkyeZ01i8QJlkEAkggA), for ARMv8 `ldxr`/`stxr` vs. ARMv8.1 `cas`)

Have one thread use CAS_weak to do 100 million increments of a std::atomic variable.  (https://preshing.com/20150402/you-can-do-any-kind-of-atomic-read-modify-write-operation/ explains how to use a CAS retry loop to implement any arbitrary atomic RMW operation on one variable, but since this is the only thread writing, CAS_strong will always succeed and we don't need a retry loop.  My Godbolt example shows doing a single increment attempt using CAS_weak vs. CAS_strong.)

To cause spurious failures for CAS_weak but not CAS_strong, have another thread reading the same variable, or writing something else in the same cache line.

Or maybe doing something like `var.fetch_or(0, std::memory_order_relaxed)` to truly get ownership of the cache line, but in a way that wouldn't affect the value.  That will *definitely* cause spurious LL/SC failures.

When you're done, 100M CAS_strong attempts will have incremented the variable from 0 to 100000000.  But 100M CAS_weak attempts will have incremented to some lower value, with the difference being the number of failures.